# Google Maps Flutter - polyline does not show up on the map

Tags: dart, fluttermap

I'm trying to create directions/routes on the map but the polyline doesn't appear on the.
Created new key without restriction, deactivated and reactivated the services: Roads API, Service Usage API, Service Management API, Stackdriver APIs, Street View APIs, Timezone API and even then without success.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHz9O.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it was exactly, I had to add the billing/payment data (on Google Cloud Platform ) and generate new keys one for Android app and one for iOS.

Comment: Please [only use](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) [_English_ here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577). If you wish to participate in Portuguese, you can do so on [pt.so].